# PieChart for every row in dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a dynamically created table and on click of view button in each row a modal opens that have the pie chart with no of leaves taken by people till date in categories like sick, vacation, maternity, paternity for the particular year.on click of 1st button the pie chart shows up https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLHTv.jpg but but if I click on any button other than 1st then I get a blank page.https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBxkc.jpg .Why blank page is appearing??please help me.

```
<td>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm view" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#{{pl.id}}_3"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" style="color:black"></i></button>
   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id= "{{pl.id}}_3" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title"><b>{{pl.employee.emp_name|title }}</b> Leave Details</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               <p>Applied leave from {{pl.start_date}} to {{pl.end_date}} for {{ pl.end_date|timeuntil:pl.start_date }} </p>
               <p>Leave applied on : {{pl.date_created}}</p>
               <p><div id="container" class="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div></p>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

My jquery Code:

```
$(document).on('click','.view', function(e){
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
    },
  title: {
    text: 'Total number of leaves applied till now'
         },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
           },
  plotOptions: {
       pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
             style: {
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                 }
            }
         },
           series: [{
             name: 'Brands',
             colorByPoint: true,
         data: [{
             name: 'Sick Leaves',
             y: 56.33
               }, {
            name: 'Casual Leaves',
            y: 24.03,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
              }, {
           name: 'Vacation Leaves',
           y: 10.3
              }, {
           name: 'Maternity Leaves',
           y: 4.77
              }, {
           name: 'Paternity Leaves',
           y: 0.91
        }]
      }]
   });
 });
```

I am using classname on click due to duplicacy in Id's but still its not workin g..Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: using classname is creating problem. It is creating chart in the first container only. Try to use variable id. you have variable `{{pl.id}}_3` use this to create unique id as `{{pl.id}}_3_highcharts` as highcharts container div id and also pass this as attribute `targetContainer="{{pl.id}}_3_highcharts"` in button. And in jquery click function get id as `targetContainer=$(this).attr('targetContainer')` use this  to highcharts as `Highcharts.chart(targetContainer, {...})`

Comment: I added {{pl.id}}_3_highcharts in button as targetContainer and in div of container as id...But I didnt understand what to write on click.classname? or id? Could you explain me

Comment: i think you are using django . As snippet cannot be recreated . so take idea from this https://jsfiddle.net/f643frer/

Comment: Its just rendering blank modal without pie chart as I mentioned in question even for the 1st button click

Comment: first you debug that unique id is generating and is thee in targetContainer

Comment: In console.log unique id is printing but i am getting Uncaugh Highcharts error #13

Comment: Corrected example: http://jsfiddle.net/yn6kdtn0/.

Comment: Its just rendering blank modal without pie chart  and in console I can see Uncaugh Highcharts error #13 on click of view button

Comment: @divya check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/46270858/3898339 to create dynamic charts