# How to create a div container for a highcharts graphic by means of code?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to create a div container for a highcharts graphic. This should be done by means of code, but I can not make it work.

The reason to create divs by code is because I have to show many graphics.

Currently I first create the div, then the id and finally the properties.

Error on graphic:

[image: Error on graphic]

Example :

http://jsfiddle.net/povyq7em/1/

My code is:

```js
var nombre="container-speed";

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("style", "width: 580px; height: 400px; float: left");
div.setAttribute("id", nombre);


var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && 
            Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },


    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickAmount: 2,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};


var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart(nombre, Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'Speed'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}));
```

```css
.highcharts-yaxis-grid .highcharts-grid-line {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<!--<div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>-->
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing one step. You need to append the element after you create it. Here's the beginning of your code:

```
var nombre="container-speed";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("style", "width: 580px; height: 400px; float: left");
div.setAttribute("id", nombre);
// APPEND ELEMENT TO document.body
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Also, I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/povyq7em/2/)

Per your request, I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/povyq7em/4/) once more. I made 3 changes. Only one of which were really important.

1. declare and value name to be used as element id and as argument for `grafica()`
   `var name = "chart-" + i;`
2. alter `setAttribute` to `div.setAttribute("id", name);`
3. ***MOST IMPORTANTLY, you changed the variable `nombre` to `name` in every place but here `var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart(name, Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {...` which you can tell, I've updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Now if I want to create N graphs, how can I do it? http://jsfiddle.net/povyq7em/3/

Comment: I modified my answer above.

One more note, if you're going to be iterating over many charts, or if there's a lot of other javascript on the page, you may have to introduce some flow control in your `for` loop